# How do I access Laravel API via Ajax

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to access an custom API built with Laravel using a Mobile Apps but getting a 404 Error. I have tried some of the solutions listed on this website but to no avail.

I am using an Ajax request to fetch data like this

```
$.ajax({

           type:'POST',
           url: 'http://192.1**.**.**/mysite/api/v1/details',
           data: {id:id},
           dataType:"json",
           success: function(data)          
            {
                alert(data);
                var comment='';

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    comment = data[i];
                }

            if (comment.userid){

                Notification('Login Successful');// display success

                setTimeout(function(){ window.location.assign('main.html'); },2000);

            }
            else if (comment.error){

                Notification(comment.error);// display error

            }

      },
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

             if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                alert("Not connected. Verify Network.");//show error

            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                alert("Requested page not found. [404]");//show error

            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                alert("Internal Server Error [500].");//show error

            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {

                alert("Requested JSON parse failed.");//show error

            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {

               alert("Time out error.");//show error

            } else if (exception === 'abort') {

                alert( "Ajax request aborted.");//show error

            } else {

                alert("Uncaught Error.\n" + jqXHR.responseText);//show error
            }

        }
});
```

I also tried changing the URL to something like this as suggested by somebody but still don't work.

```
url: 'http://192.1**.**.**/mysite/public/index.php/api/v1/details'
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function()
    {
        Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
        Route::resource('details', 'DetailsController');
    });
```

Please I am stuck badly, I need detail help.

Comment: Doesn't look like a javascript problem, you need to post your routes. What is the sites base url `http://192.1**.**.**/mysite/public/` ? Can you provide info on the API you are using?

Comment: I am accessing the Apps on my localhost. IP: `192.***.***.***` enable me to connect to `Wamp` via `Wifi` and the connection is working. I have updated the codes above with my `Route.php` codes

Comment: Is the Laravel app working for other requests? The route suggests you need to be authenticated to access it, does the authentication work fine?

Comment: yes, but the Mobile Apps seem not to understand the URL cause I get the `404 Not Found` error.

Comment: So it works on everything but android? I'm confused, can you be clear on what is and isn't working.

Comment: the `url: 'http://192.1**.**.**/mysite/api/v1/details` is giving a `404 Error`

Comment: Yes, but other parts of the app are working fine?

Comment: yes, they are working fine

Comment: So a post request to `http://192.1**.**.**/mysite/api/v1/users` works without a problem?

Comment: what was the problem?